# bound standalone google app script to google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a google app script that is bound to google sheet later I moved it as standalone script inside a google drive folder. I thought I will be able to reuse it across multiple sheet. Now I am not able to find any way to run standalone script inside my google sheets. Please suggest.

Comment: Use your standalone script as library and then import that library in a tiny script project attached with every spreadsheet. From there, now you can run. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your standalone script you can access your spreadsheets and work this way with your files.

Use something like this to get a set of spreadsheets (pseudocode)

```
var ssList = ['...','...']
for each element in ssList do:
SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssList[element]);
```

Then you can reuse your code and access multiple spreadsheets.

But it is not possible to access multiple apps script files, only one file is bound to your spreadsheet.